# Concepts for managing inventory and orders with specific fulfillment date

Tags: inventory, base-stock

I'm modeling a fairly basic order and inventory management system but with a use case that doesn't seem very common (or at least hard to look up online and in books about operations): **the order fulfillment date is specific and sometimes far in the future**.

A simplified description: a hotel wants to sell items during or after the reservation process. A room can be reserved for the next day or the next year. The order fulfillment (= item delivery) is at check-in time. There is no shipping delay, as the stock is maintain at the hotel and delivered into the room in person.

I've been able to define some basic concepts to help figure out the scope of the system, specifically: orders with a scheduled fulfillment date (i.e. not "ASAP"), on-hand inventory, stock reservations, and a simple, low-scale replenishment process.

However, I'd like to better define an important operational aspect: **reservations for 1 year in the future should not result in a stock reservation against on-hand inventory**. This is for a few reasons:

1. The hotel will definitely replenish the inventory before then
2. If the on-hand inventory is reserved for 1 year in the future, it's inventory the hotel cannot sell and use to fulfill more recent orders with a near-future fulfillment date
3. The inventory might be perishable

Are there any resources, best practices, case studies around these needs?

What concepts could help me define how far in the future an order results in a stock reservation against on-hand inventory vs. a reservation to be matched with inventory when the time comes?

Comment: you can list them as, for example, 'confirmed orders' .These are then taken into account in planning calculations the moment the fulfillment date falls within lead time. Make sure you don't take the entire amount into account because you already have your calculations based on historical sales data.

Comment: @Steven01123581321 You're right about the calculations, that's helpful, thanks! Not sure about the naming of "confirmed orders" since, from a broader perspective, the sale was the confirmation. English isn't my first language so I'd love to find the right terminology here and, ideally, resources that address this kind of concepts. This can't be a unique problem?